# How do I export selected cells in EXCEL 2010 as HTML. Cell range may be different on each export?

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am looking to export selected cells in EXCEL 2010, to an HTML file.

The selected cells will change before each export so the cell range can't be hard coded into the VBA.
The Macro I have recorded for one export produced this VBA:

```
Sub ExportHTML()

    Range("A1").Select '
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
        "Q:\Library Resource Centre\AR\AR Project 2015-16\Admin.htm", "Export", _
        "A1:AI26", xlHtmlStatic, "Admin_20257", "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I have not been able to find a way of changing: "A1:AI26" to match the cells selected.

I hope someone can help, Thank you.

Comment: How is the range determined? Is it the used range, an actual selection made by the user? The method depends on how to determin what to export.

Comment: The cells are currently selected using the VBA code:   
`code`
    Range("A1").Select 
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select `code`

   It is these selected cells that I would like to export.

Answer (score 1):

Without further optimization:

```
Sub ExportHTML()
  dim wks as worksheet
  dim strRng as String

  set wks=Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1) 'Assuming you are working with the 1st Worksheet. Adjust insex number if needed.
  strRng = wks.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).address

  With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
      "Q:\Library Resource Centre\AR\AR Project 2015-16\Admin.htm", "Export", _
      wks.Name & "!" & strRng, xlHtmlStatic, "Admin_20257", "")
      .Publish (True)
      .AutoRepublish = False
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run the VBA, I get an error:  

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Publish' of object 'PublishObject' failed

 - Any idea, what is going on? How to fix the error?

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Just tested the code with some data at my place. Are you running it from the right workbook/worksheet? You do not set those, so it could be something about changing worksheets (Without definition range uses the active sheet).

Comment: Edited the code to be more precise. Adjust the index number of the worksheet and try again. Both versions worked for me. Now the worksheet is clearly defined.

Comment: Not too sure what was is going on, now I get an another error: Compile error: Expected Function or Variable - I have directly copied and pasted the code, run the VBA.

Comment: Copy&Pasted back to a test workbook and it is running fine... So make sure:
The macro is running in the same workbook as the data is, else adjustments need to be made, since the macro asumes the workbook it is used in to be the one to work with.
The worksheet containing the data is the first worksheet, else you need to adjust the 'set wks.=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` to the corresponding worksheet, or use the name of the worksheet in quotation marks, instead of the index number.
Can't think of more obstacles on the coding side.

Comment: Hi, just to make sure, the worksheet you want to publish in HTML is called "Export" right ? If not, you have to change "Export" by wks.name,,,

Comment: Just to confirm, "Export" is the first worksheet... I rewrote the code with fixed address as in my first post of the code, when ran I get the same error... I logged off the computer to close any open processes and then back on, opened up Excel, opened workbook from recent workbooks, ran the VBA and it worked, re-ran the VBA and it failed with the same error... Pasted Blind Seer's VBA code back and saved, followed the same steps, it failed with the same error on first run of VBA... I may look at just publishing the whole sheet as html (not ideal but will suffice)... Thanks for all your help.